# ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") does not work with firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, activexobject

My code is like this:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

When I use Firefox, I found that an error

> "ReferenceError:ActiveXObject is not defined"

when `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` is run, it seems that, unlike IE, Firefox does not support ActiveXObject, may I ask, if I cannot change the javascript code, may I make it work?
Thank you very much

Comment: ActiveX are an *Internet Explorer thing*. Other browsers have specific custom non portable solution for same problem. Btw even Edge dropped them.

Comment: hi, thank you, may I ask is it possible to make some plugin? If I do not modify the code it will not work? Thank you

Comment: I do not know about Firefox plug-ins to access file system. Sorry. However I'd change point of view. What do you have to do? Which browsers you gave to support?

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. ok, now my question is, is it possible to write file by firefox, modifying the javascript is also OK, thank you